# CheckJNI is not getting enabled on Android Lollipop ART

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I am writing a native application in Android. During development as expected there will be crashes in the native layer. Previously CheckJNI option was working but recently after the phone got upgraded to Lollipop ART, Check JNI option is not getting enabled at all. Tried

```
adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1
```

Still getting the below message

```
AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
```

Observed this message as well

```
art     : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
```

But when application crashes in the native layer not getting the backtrace/callstack. Please share the information if anyone knows how to get the backtrace for the native crash in Android ART Lollipop.

Device I am using Moto-G 2nd Generation and developing application for Lollipop and above.

Tried googling and searching in stack overflow as well, but not useful.

Comment: Guys, it's ok to down vote. Please leave the reason in the comments. If you guys are un-necessarily down voting then other users will not be interested in looking to this question. Due to which I loose help from the community.

Comment: ART is generally less permissive than Dalvik. So most of the beloved CheckJNI features are not relevant anymore (or always relevant if you will). This said, ART silently turns "on" its extra checks for debug build of your app.

Comment: @AlexCohn So, does it mean in ART we will not be getting the native stacktrace?

Comment: What kind of crash do you get?

Comment: CheckJNI just adds additional checks that may be reported as an abort. It shouldn't affect the debuggerd stack dump. Are you seeing missed checks (e.g. you can now pass non-class objects when a class object is required), or does an arbitrary crash not result in a stack dump in logcat?

Comment: In the crittercism it shows SIGSEGV as the crash but not getting the callstack in the logcat. Crittercism I have, doesn't have the full licencse, so I cannot decode the symbols.